# ObservableCollection<> not loading properly

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime

I am trying to implement filtering on an `ObservableCollection<>`. My current `ObservableCollection<Payee>` is working fine as an `ItemsSource` on a `GridView`. I added a second `ObservableCollection<Payee>` called `FilteredPayees` to use as the `ItemsSource`. For some reason, when I try to filter the items, the `GridView` is showing up blank.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void FilterPayees()
{
    if (!_settings.ShowInactivePayees)
    {
        var filtered = _payees.Where(p => p.IsOpen == true);
        _filteredPayees = new ObservableCollection<Payee>(filtered);
    }
    else
    {
        _filteredPayees = _payees;
    }
    this.FilteredPayees = _filteredPayees;
}
```

Basically, if the `ShowInactivePayees` setting is turned off, it should filter out the inactive payees. If it is on, then just use the full `_payees` collection. The strange thing, if I change the last line to:

```
this.FilteredPayees = _payees;
```

then the `GridView` will display all of the payees, just as it should if the "show inactive payees" settings is turned on. I set breakpoints and the `_filteredPayees` collection has 35 items in it (or 65 when not filtering). It does not appear to be any type of "object not set to an instance of an object" or anything like that. Is there some reason that

```
this.FilteredPayees = _payees;
```

would work, but

```
_filteredPayees = _payees;
this.FilteredPayees = _filteredPayees;
```

would not?

**EDIT**

I was able to get it to work for now by getting rid of the `FilteredPayees` property. I just filter the original `Payees` collection in the `OnNavigatedTo()` event handler, which is exactly the same place where I was calling `FilteredPayees()`.

```
// load payees
var payees = await _payeesRepository.LoadAllAsync();

if (!_settings.ShowInactivePayees)
{
    payees = payees.Where(p => p.IsOpen);
}
payees = payees.OrderBy(p => p.CompanyName);

this.Payees = new ObservableCollection<Payee>(payees);
```

The only part I added was the `if (!_settings.ShowInactivePayees) ...` block. My reasoning to use the `FilteredPayees` property was so that I could have the full collection loaded in the `Payees` property and not need to reload if the `ShowInactivePayees` setting was changed - just change the filter of the collection.

Comment: short answer: no - long answer: it depends...is there any other code changing `_filteredPayees`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a new object to `FilteredPayees` property, so `GridView` has to be notified that the property `FilteredPayees` is changed. There should be `RaisePropertyChanged("FilteredPayees")` or your notification code in the setter of `FilteredPayees`.

Also, the binding mode of `GridView.ItemsSource` should not be `BindingMode.OneTime`.

Comment: I am using PrismMVVM, and my `ViewModel` inherits the `Prism.Mvvm.ViewModel` class. My properties look like this:        public `ObservableCollection<Payee> Payees
        {
            get { return _payees; }
            set { base.SetProperty(ref _payees, value); }
        }`

        `public ObservableCollection<Payee> FilteredPayees
        {
            get { return _filteredPayees; }
            set { base.SetProperty(ref _filteredPayees, value); }
        }`

Comment: If I use the `Payees` as the `ItemsSource` everything works fine. Even if I use the `FilteredPayees` and just set it `= _payees;` instead of `_filteredPayees;`.

Comment: I believe it does have something to do with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but everything with `FilteredPayees` is set up the same as `Payees`, and that property is working fine. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering a collection in WPF it may be easier to use `ICollectionView`. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<Payee> _payees;

    private ICollectionView _filteredPayees;

    public ICollectionView FilteredPayees
    {
        get { return _filteredPayees; }
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        _payees = GetPayees();
        _filteredPayees = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_payees);
        _filteredPayees.Filter = FilterPayees;
    }

    private bool FilterPayees(object item)
    {
        var payee = item as Payee;

        if (payee == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (_settings.ShowInactivePayees)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return payee.IsOpen;
    }
}
```

You can bind the property `FilteredPayees` like any other property. The advantage is, that you don't need two properties and you can avoid the logic of which collection you want to bind.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using WPF. `ICollectionView` is not available in WinRT projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
_filteredPayees = new ObservableCollection<Payee>(filtered);
```

Here you create a completely new object, and that's not something ObservableCollection can automatically observe. The possible solution is to set ItemsSource on your GridView again after this line.